# How to call this function: void SeatMakeEmpty(Seat* seat) from main

Tags: c

I want to call a function but am not able to. I always get errors. The program asks the user to input a seat number:

```
scanf("%d", &seatNum);
```

With the seat number entered, it will call this function:

```
void SeatMakeEmpty(Seat* seat) {
    strcpy((*seat).firstName, "empty");
    strcpy((*seat).lastName,  "empty");
    (*seat).amountPaid = 0;
    return;
}
```

How can I call that function such that `firstName` and `lastName` are set to "empty", and `amountPaid` is 0?

Comment: Juan, I have rewritten this post a bit to read more cleanly. Please look it over to ensure that it still says what you were trying to say.

Comment: You are leaving out too much information.  You say you get errors.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: `SeatMakeEmpty(&someVariableThatsASeat);`?

Comment: No data declaration for 'seat'.  No code around the allocation/initialization of 'seat' instances and its members:(

Comment: Modify main() to allow the user to enter command 'd', followed by the user entering a seat number. Call SeatMakeEmpty() to delete the seat. That is what I have to do inside my code. So basically in main I add an if (user key == 'd'); then do this: ask user for seat number. Then jump to SeatMakeEmpty with the seat the user entered. That function will basically put empty to first name and lastname and also put 0 to amount paid for that seat.

Comment: I have used this to call that function but I doesn't work: SeatMakeEmpty(&seatNum);

Answer (score 1):

One apparent problem is, you are reading the seat number like this: `scanf("%d", &seatNum);`, which means, that `seatNum` is a decimal (hence the `%d`), so a number.

However, the function `SeatMakeEmpty(Seat* seat)` requests an pointer-argument of type `Seat`! You will have to pass the correct argument. In your call `SeatMakeEmpty(&seatNum);`, you are passing it a pointer to an `int`, instead of a `Seat`. So in your case, this means you have to:

- Look for the correct seat, corresponding to the number `seatNum`, which has been provided by the user.
- Get that seat and pass *it* as an argument to `SeatMakeEmpty`.